# Umbraco Images wont load load without www

Tags: umbraco

I  have a website which works perfectly fine in Umbraco when loading via www.testsite.com

However, when I navigate to the website via the url testsite.com, content is displayed but the images are not.

Anything I need to do get the images displayed?  I am currently running on Umbraco 6.2

Comment: How you are rendering images in template(view/Pages)

Comment: Iam using the IPublishedItem Umbraco.TypedMedia(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("heroImage"))

Comment: Like to add when i go to testsite.com/umbraco all images are the Umbraco orange circle image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a config preventing hot image linking.  I added testsite.com in the allowed host names

Answer (score 0):

A quick but not all that awesome fix would to set a domain hostname I believe. Right click on your home node select 'manage hostnames' and set it to www.testsite.com. It works for links so I guess it might for images?

Comment: I dont have that option in Umbraco

Comment: Found it, its culture and hostnames.  I added www.testsite.com and  the images still dont show up.

Comment: Baah, I thought that would override all urls to use www Do you have both www and non www setup in your DNS records?